# Java. Создание image и последующая передача

Tags: java, изображения, graphics

Мне необходимо создать класс, в котором при помощи Graphics, рисуешь необходимые элементы из линий, после сохраняешь их в image и передаёшь основному классу.
Сейчас я через второе приложение сохраняю картинку и в Основном классе считываю её из директории.
Вот код. Плохо понимаю как это вообще возможно сделать. Возможно нужно создать метод который будет возвращать image.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.;
import java.awt.;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.*;
public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main main_window = new Main();
        main_window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main_window.setLocation(0,0);
        Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
        int vert = sSize.height;
        int hor = sSize.width;
        main_window.setSize(hor,vert);
        main_window.setResizable(false);
        MainField game_field = new MainField();
        game_field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        main_window.add(game_field);
        main_window.setVisible(true);
        game_field.setLayout(null);
    }

    private static void onRepaint (Graphics g ){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(50,50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2D = img.createGraphics();
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Рисую что необходимо
        g2D.dispose();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("src/lol/Питание 0.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class MainField extends JPanel{
        protected void paintComponent (Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            onRepaint(g);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: сохранять обязательно? или нужно просто создать изображение в одном объекте и передать в другой?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman. Нужно создать его в одном объекте и передать в другой. Причём что там нарисовано должен определять я.